# Issue with click event in mobile IE

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework to create a hybrid app. The app is working fine in all devices (android,ios and windows), and also url is working fine in android,ios browsers but the problem is with windows mobile IE browser.

Problem:
Click functionality is working only when we double tap. But in desktop IE it is working on single tap only .

Comment: @mounika its already a known issue please refer this [link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2885)

Comment: @Webruster actually my issue is different from that, My issue is event, assume alert is triggered only on double click. It is working fine in desktop IE but the problem is with Window's phn IE browser